# Nonlinear logistic regression package in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, non-linear-regression

Is there an R package that performs nonlinear logistic regression?

In more words: I have `glm`, with which I can go `glm (cbind (success, failure) ~ variable 1 + variable2, data = df, family = binomial (link = 'logit'))`, and I can use `nls` to go `nls (y ~ a * x^2 + b * x + c, data = df)`.

I'd like to have some function that would take the formula `cbind (success, failure) ~ int - slo * x + gap / (1 + x / sca)` (where `x`, `success`, and `failure` are the only data and everything else are parametres) with a `binomial (link = 'logit')` family, i.e. combine both things. I've been scouring Google and haven't been able to find anything like that.

Comment: Did you check https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gnm/vignettes/gnmOverview.pdf ?

Comment: I didn't read all of it but a ctrl+F does not seem to find `logistic` except for a logistic _function_ and `binomial` doesn't find a logit link function and all the examples use something called `Dref` and I have no idea what that is. I tried using `gnm` with the formula I described there though and it gave me a `object 'int' not found` error. If you tell me it can be done there though I'll look further into it.

Comment: This blog post shows you how to do it with gmm, but you will need to construct some equations and CHECK THIS GUYS LOGIC CAREFULLY! https://www.r-bloggers.com/nonlinear-gmm-with-r-example-with-a-logistic-regression/

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, this blog post seems to be showing me how to do a regular linear logistic regression instead of the nonlinear one I'm trying to estimate. Is that not the case?

Comment: you don't need nonlinear least squares to fit ax^2 + bx +c ... that's linear in x and x^2

Comment: That is correct, but `ax^2 + bx + c` is not what I'm trying to fit, what I'm trying to fit is `int - slo * x + gap / (1 + x / sca)`

Comment: Are gap and sca data or parameters to be estimated?

Comment: other possibilities are `bbmle::mle2` and the `rethinking` package (Github-only)

Comment: x is the only data, gap and sca and slo and int are all parametres

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `gnlm::bnlr()`.  The default link is logit and you can specify a nonlinear function of data and parameters.  I include two answers depending on whether or not `gap` and `sca` are data or parameters.

```
library(gnlm)
```

In the case of `gap` and `sca` are data:

```
## if gap and sca are data:
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(  x = rnorm(10),
                  gap = rnorm(10),
                  sca = rnorm(10),
                    y = rbinom(10,1,0.4))
y_cbind = cbind(dat$y, 1-dat$y)
attach(dat)
bnlr(y=y_cbind, mu = ~ int - slo * x + gap / (1 + x / sca), pmu = c(0,0))
```

Output:

```
Call:
bnlr(y = y_cbind, mu = ~int - slo * x + gap/(1 + x/sca), pmu = c(0, 
    0))

binomial distribution

Response: y_cbind 

Log likelihood function:
{
    m <- plogis(mu1(p))
    -sum(wt * (y[, 1] * log(m) + y[, 2] * log(1 - m)))
}

Location function:
~int - slo * x + gap/(1 + x/sca)

-Log likelihood    2.45656 
Degrees of freedom 8 
AIC                4.45656 
Iterations         8 

Location parameters:
     estimate      se
int    -1.077  0.8827
slo    -1.424  1.7763

Correlations:
       1      2
1 1.0000 0.1358
2 0.1358 1.0000
```

In the case `gap` and `sca` are parameters:

```
## if gap and sca are parameters:
detach(dat)
set.seed(2)
dat <- data.frame(  x = rbinom(1000,1,0.3),
                    y = rbinom(1000,1,0.4))
y_cbind = cbind(dat$y, 1-dat$y)
attach(dat)
bnlr(y=y_cbind, mu = ~ int - slo * x + gap / (1 + x / sca), pmu = c(0,0,0,1))
```

Output:

```
Call:
bnlr(y = y_cbind, mu = ~int - slo * x + gap/(1 + x/sca), pmu = c(0, 
    0, 0, 1))

binomial distribution

Response: y_cbind 

Log likelihood function:
{
    m <- plogis(mu1(p))
    -sum(wt * (y[, 1] * log(m) + y[, 2] * log(1 - m)))
}

Location function:
~int - slo * x + gap/(1 + x/sca)

-Log likelihood    672.9106 
Degrees of freedom 996 
AIC                676.9106 
Iterations         7 

Location parameters:
     estimate      se
int  -0.22189  2.1007
slo   0.03828  3.6051
gap  -0.20273  2.0992
sca   0.99885  0.3956

Correlations:
          1       2        3       4
1    1.0000   1.859  -0.9993 -281.45
2    1.8587   1.000  -1.8592  -82.06
3   -0.9993  -1.859   1.0000  281.64
4 -281.4530 -82.061 281.6443    1.00
```